# How can I get real point position of WPF Polyline points?

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, polyline, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to draw some marks (red circles) over my WPF PolyLine points.

So I can get position of each PolyLine.Point and draw my mark.

[image]

And this is ok, but problem appears when Polyline **Stretch** is applied!

So when **Stretch** is applied point coordinates not equals to real position of point on screen.

[image]

Any ideas how to get real point position on screen when **Stretch** is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `Transform` from the Polyline's `RenderedGeometry`:

```
var transform = polyline.RenderedGeometry.Transform;

foreach (var point in polyline.Points)
{
    var transformedPoint = transform.Transform(point);
}
```